# what is docker purge/clean data do?

Tags: docker

in my mac i have dashboard menu in docker application, when my images increases alot then i usually reset my docker by purge my whole docker environment with this app.

i usually open docker -> dashboard -> move to troubleshot -> clean / purge data,
and voila all image, container, volume, network is clean purely.

i sometime use other command like docker system prune all but it do less then purge / clean data above.

would any one could explain to me what docker purge/clean data do so i can make bash file instead of click menu by menu?

Comment: Yeah, I have the same issue. docker system prune -a does not clean up space while Clear/Purge data from Dashboard does.